# How to Populate Dropdown inside the Gridview?

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdown inside the gridview template field.

```
<asp:templatefield headertext="Bill Period">
<itemtemplate>
<asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="cboBillPeriod"></asp:dropdownlist>
</itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```

I want to populate the dropdown
i could i do it? can any please help me.

Comment: you may use `RowDataBound` event of grid view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could bind the dropdown in `OnRowDataBound` event of GridView as follow:

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="ContactName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Country">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>' Visible = "false" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

With the help of `FindControl` method you will be able to get the dropdown control and then you could play with that control.

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Find the DropDownList in the Row
        DropDownList ddlCountries = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlCountries") as DropDownList);
        ddlCountries.DataSource = GetData("SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Customers");
        ddlCountries.DataTextField = "Country";
        ddlCountries.DataValueField = "Country";
        ddlCountries.DataBind();

        //Add Default Item in the DropDownList
        ddlCountries.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));

        // Select the Country of Customer in DropDownList
        string country = (e.Row.FindControl("lblCountry") as Label).Text;
        ddlCountries.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for your dropdown in your gridview.

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Condition" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="40px>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlConditions" runat="server" >  
            </asp:DropDownList>
          </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Under your grid "RowDataBound" event, you will bind your dropdown in code behind using dropdown id.

```
DropDownList ddlConditions2 = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlConditions") as DropDownList);
                DataTable dt = _reader.GetDataTableByCommandFromStoredProc("getYourDropdownData");
                ddlConditions2.DataSource = dt;
                ddlConditions2.DataTextField = "ConditionName";
                ddlConditions2.DataValueField = "Id";
                ddlConditions2.DataBind();
                ddlConditions2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `RowDataBound` event of grid view. For more Check that [Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1853665.aspx/1).

Answer (score -3):

In `Rowdatabound` event of `Gridview`, try to bind your drop-down.